# Sumar los precios de una columna según el id

Tags: mysql

Como sumar precio_sin_desc de IdContrato
RESULTADO ESPERADO EJEMPLO IdContrato 2 precio_sin_desc  5460.6

```
SELECT C.id AS IdContrato, 
((CPD.unit_price) -
((CPD.unit_price) * CA.discount_percentage) / 100) * CPD.quantity
    AS precio_sin_desc,
FROM contracts_periods AS CP 
INNER JOIN contracts AS C ON C.id = CP.contract_id AND C.creator_company_id = (1)   
INNER JOIN contracts_periods_details AS CPD ON CPD.contract_period_id = CP.id
INNER JOIN contracts_articles AS CA ON CA.contract_id = C.id
WHERE CP.id IN (
        SELECT CPP.contract_period_id FROM contracts_period_payments AS CPP
        WHERE CPP.paid_out = 0
)
GROUP BY CP.id, CPD.id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simplemente modifica tu consulta y agrega un `SUM()` a `precio_sin_desc`, algo así: `SUM(((CPD.unit_price) -
((CPD.unit_price) * CA.discount_percentage) / 100) * CPD.quantity) as suma_precio`

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Usa `SUM` y `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT t1.IdContrato, SUM(t1.precio_sin_desc) AS sumPrecioSinDesc
FROM
(
    SELECT C.id AS IdContrato, 
    ((CPD.unit_price) -
    ((CPD.unit_price) * CA.discount_percentage) / 100) * CPD.quantity
        AS precio_sin_desc,
    FROM contracts_periods AS CP 
    INNER JOIN contracts AS C ON C.id = CP.contract_id AND C.creator_company_id = (1)   
    INNER JOIN contracts_periods_details AS CPD ON CPD.contract_period_id = CP.id
    INNER JOIN contracts_articles AS CA ON CA.contract_id = C.id
    WHERE CP.id IN (
            SELECT CPP.contract_period_id FROM contracts_period_payments AS CPP
            WHERE CPP.paid_out = 0
    )
) t1
GROUP BY t1.IdContrato
```